# Home page sections layout

Tags: html, css

I'm realizing a new website. I have attached an image of how I would like it to be the base of my home page.
I ask you please what is the best method to create these three colored sections.

The first blue in which to insert the title.
The second light blue with black borders in which to include names.
And the rest light gray where I will add a table containing input boxes and below I will add the text.

I state that I have no problem formatting title, tables, texts, input boxes, etc.

I only can't get the effect of the three sections like in the image. I either tried to use **div** but I think it's not the best solution because I get unwanted margins.

How would you do?

Thanks :)

```css
.div0 {
background-color: red;
margin-top: 0%;
margin-bottom: 0%;
}

.title1 {
font-family: Arial;
font-weight: normal;
color:  black;
font-size: 428%;
margin-top: 0.7%;
margin-bottom: 0%;
text-align: center;
bgcolor: red;
}

.td1 {
text-align: center;
}

.div1 {
background-color: blue;
margin-top: 0%;
margin-bottom: 0%;
}
```

```html
<BODY>

<div class="div0">
 <H1 class="title1">
 Title
 </H1>
</div>

<div class="div1">
 <table width="96%" align="center">
  <tr class="tr1">
   <td class="td1" width="1/7">
   Name1
   </td>
   <td class="td1" width="1/7">
   Name2
   </td>
   <td class="td1" width="1/7">
   Name3
   </td>
   <td class="td1" width="1/7">
   Name4
   </td>
   <td class="td1" width="1/7">
   Name5
   </td>
   <td class="td1" width="1/7">
   Name6
   </td>
   <td class="td1" width="1/7">
   Name7
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="div2">

</div>

</BODY>
```

[image]

Comment: `<div>` is *absolutely* the best way to go about this. You'll want one `<div>` for each section, with several `<span>` elements for the names. Have you tried anything so far in this regard?

Comment: Please, share what you tried so far, and be more specific with what you're having difficulties with. Stack overflow is meant to help you troubleshot code, not develop stuff on demand, from the ground, and it's hard to get the problem you're having wthout seeing what you tried. Any doubts, take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ok thanks both! Now I added the code so you can see. With the divs I got these white margins

Comment: @ObsidianAge that is definitely not the case. In fact there is nothing in this design that requires either `div` or `span`, as it's fairly simple and every element has a proper adequate semantic tag that can (should) be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimal markup and css for something similar to that, using css grid and flexbox, would be more or less like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 120px max-content 1fr;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
  color: yellow;
}

.header__title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar {
  display:    flex;
  background: lightblue;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
}

.navbar__item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.content {
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
  
  <header class="header">
    <h1 class="header__title">Title</h1>
  </header>
  
  <nav class="navbar">
    <a href="#" class="navbar__item">item</a>
    <a href="#" class="navbar__item">item</a>
    <a href="#" class="navbar__item">item</a>
    <a href="#" class="navbar__item">item</a>
    <a href="#" class="navbar__item">item</a>
    <a href="#" class="navbar__item">item</a>
    <a href="#" class="navbar__item">item</a>
  </nav>
    
  <article class="content">
    
  </article>
</main>
```

I recommend you do a bit of studying about html5 semantic markup, to help you know where to use each kind of tag in their appropriate context.

Comment: I will follow your advice about studying html5 semantic markup :D

Comment: Henrique, can I ask you for advice privately?

Answer (score 1):

It is not good practise using tables for the structure of a page. For a structure you may use `display:flex` or `float:left`. The first stylesheet removes differences between browsers and give some good readable default values for many devices. The second stylesheet is your styling (see below)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>My page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
  <header id="header">
    <h1 class="title1">Title</h1>
  </header>
  <nav id="nav">
    <ul>
    <li>Name1</li>
    <li>Name2</li>
    <li>Name3</li>
    <li>Name4</li>
    <li>Name5</li>
    <li>Name6</li>
    <li>Name7</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main id="main">
    <p>Your content</p>
  </main>
  <footer id="footer">
    Footer
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

And the css in file "style.css"

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
#page {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-top: 0.7%;
}
#header {
  background-color: red;
}
#header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#nav::after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}
#nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#nav ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 14.2857%;
  padding: 5px 0px 7px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
#main {
  min-height: 5em;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: silver;
}
#footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}
```